# Why is my if statement not giving an output in Python3?

Tags: python-3.x

I am very new when it comes to coding but wanted to jump straight into it, so I decided to do a number guessing project without looking at what someone else did. I have run into a issue where I don't know why it isn't outputting the if statement. Could anyone give me some suggestions please? Thank you!

**Edit**: don't mind the print function for the answer, that was for testing the if statement.

```
#Imports
import random

#Variables
A=random.randint(0,400)
RNlist=list(range(0,401))

print("Hello! and welcome to the Number Test! " "\n" "Today we will be guessing a number between 0 and 400. Can you guess right? We will see... ")
print(A)
U=input("Time to guess! What will it be? ")

if U==A:
    C=input("Correct! Your good at this! Want to go for another round? " ["yes", "no"])
    if C=="yes":
        U
    elif C=="no":
        exit()
```

Comment: How about you try `U=int(input("Time to guess! What will it be? "))`.  However I am not sure what this construction is supposed to be doing: `if C=="yes": U`...

Answer (score -2):

The best way is to define a function, so you can recursively call it

```
>>> import random
>>> def game():
...   A=random.randint(0,3)
...   print("Hello! and welcome to the Number Test! " "\n" "Today we will be guessing a number between 0 and 400. Can you guess right? We will see... ")
...   U=input("Time to guess! What will it be? ")
...   while int(U)!=A:
...       print("Wrong, try again! ")
...       U=input("Time to guess! What will it be? ")
...   C=input("Correct! Your good at this! Want to go for another round? ['yes', 'no']")
...   print(C)
...   if C=='yes':
...       game()
...   elif C=='no':
...       exit()
...
>>> game()
Hello! and welcome to the Number Test!
Today we will be guessing a number between 0 and 400. Can you guess right? We will see...
Time to guess! What will it be? 0
Wrong, try again!
Time to guess! What will it be? 1
Wrong, try again!
Time to guess! What will it be? 2
Wrong, try again!
Time to guess! What will it be? 3
Correct! Your good at this! Want to go for another round? ['yes', 'no']yes
yes
Hello! and welcome to the Number Test!
Today we will be guessing a number between 0 and 400. Can you guess right? We will see...
Time to guess! What will it be?
```

Comment: No recursion is not the way to start over. Use a while loop.